# java class to create instance of itself

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an instance of the holding class using reflection but i keep getting the following exception

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
>   com.myproject.fresh.stubClasses.TestModel     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)

```
public class TestModel extends Model {

    @Override
    public Schema getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

    public TestModel newModel(){

        TestModel model = null;

        try{

            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getClass().toString());
            Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
            model = (TestModel) ctor.newInstance();

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `getClass().toString()` replace with `getClass().getName()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `getClass().toString()` returns (for example) `class com.myproject.fresh.stubClasses.TestModel`, with a stray `class` at the beginning. If you use `getName()` instead, it should work:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getClass().getName());
```

though if this is "real" code (rather than just figuring-stuff-out code), it's easier to just write this:

```
Class<?> clazz = getClass();
```

That also lets you make better use of generics:

```
Class<? extends TestModel> clazz = getClass();
Constructor<? extends TestModel> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
model = ctor.newInstance();
```

or:

```
return getClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Answer (score 3):

This line here:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getClass().toString());
```

is wrong.

Do not use the `toString()` method to get the class's name. Use `getName()` instead.

The following example describes their differences:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Test.class.toString()); //prints "class <package>.Test"
        System.out.println(Test.class.getName()); //prints "<package>.Test"
    }
}
```

The extraneous "class" text before the class name is throwing off the 'forName' method.

In the end, this is what the line should look like:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getClass().getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using just getClass().newInstance()?